# Rails before_update doesn't trigger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model `Article` `name:string description:text number_of_comments:integer open_for_comments:boolean`.

I want to block the possibility to comment when there is more than 5 comments but it doesn't work.

When I create an Article `open_for_comments` is always `nil`. That means that it doesn't trigger.

Can anyone help?

Here's a code

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_update :close_comments, if: :more_than_five_comments?

  def more_than_five_comments?
    self.number_of_comments >5 ? true : false
  end 

  def close_comments
    self.open_for_comments = false
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a `Comment` model? If so, is it related to `Article`? If `Article has_many :comments` then you should only need to have a method for `open_for_comments` and not need either the counter `number_of_comments` or the boolean `open_for_comments`.

Comment: **When I create an Article open_for_comments is always NIL. That means that it doesn't trigger.** If you **create** an article, a before_update callback will **not** be triggered as it only works on existing records. You may want to look at either before_create or before_save instead. Whichever suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a new Article the default value for open_for_comments is going to be nil.

If you added a migration to set the default for open_for_comments to be true, when Article is initially created it would be set to to true instead of Nil.

The way that I read how it is set up right now here is what's happening when you create an article:

```
Article.create(name: "New Article, description: "Example description")
  -> <Article id: 1, name: "New Article", description: "Example description:, number_of_comments: nil, open_for_comments: nil > # unless within your migrations you have them set to a default value
```

so when you are are calling your before_update your essentially saying `nil > 5 ? true : false`

Migration:

```
class ChangeOpenForCommentsToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change 
    change_column :articles, :open_for_comments, :boolean, :default => true
  end
```

That being said, this isn't the "railsy" way to do it. You should be using associations if you have a Comment model.

Comment: Think i got. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: No problem. Was this the answer you were looking for?